# Adjust size of element between two elements

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have an elementary question, though I can't find any answer:

I have a RelativeLayout with some elements inside. I have some space left at the bottom which I want to fill with some element such as..LinearLayout. What should be the parameters to make it scale this way - "align yourself with the bottom(alignParentBottom), but at the same time, stretch yourself until you reach the first element above you"?

Is there a possible solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/upper_view_id"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set following attributes.

```
android:allignParentBottom=true
```

and

```
android:layoutBelow="id of element upto which you want to stretch this element"
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: As Arslan has pointed out - fill parent must be provided also. But thank you for your time to answer!